# how to create a man page using fpm?

Tags: linux, debian, packaging, fpm

I am using `fpm` to generate my debian package from a directory which contains my bash script.

The directory has only this bash script. I want to add a man page to the package so that I can view the man page using `man` command after installing my deb package . how to do so ?

What's the `fpm` option or command to include the created manpage in the package ?

Comment: If you don't want to learn proper `man`, the Perl POD format is a convenient and slightly more modern markup language which can produce quite traditional-looking man pages with fairly minimal overhead and learning curve. See [`man perlpod`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `usr/share/man` with your man pages to the option on `fpm`

In my `makefile` which runs `fpm` I have `ronn` which creates man.5 pages from markdown.

```
@mkdir -p pkg/tmp/usr/share/man/man5
@ronn -r README.md --pipe > pkg/tmp/usr/share/man/man5/example.5

(cd pkg && \
fpm -s dir -t deb -C tmp ---other-stuff usr/share/man)
```

See the docs example: 
https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use-cases/make-install.html#package-up-the-manpages-create-nodejs-doc

Comment: How to change the control fields in fpm ? is there an option to add or change control fields of debian in fpm ?

Comment: --deb-custom-control FILEPATH (deb only) Custom version of the Debian control file.